# multiprocessing Queue deadlock when spawn multi threads in one process

Tags: python-2.7, deadlock, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I created two processes, one process that spawn multi threads is response for writing data to Queue, the other is reading data from Queue.  It always deadblock in high frequent, fewer not. Especially when you add sleep in run method in write module(comment in codes).  Let me put my codes below:

***environments:*** python2.7

**main.py**

```
    from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
    from write import write
    from read import read

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        record_queue = Queue()
        table_queue = Queue()

        pw = Process(target=write,args=[record_queue, table_queue])
        pr = Process(target=read,args=[record_queue, table_queue])

        pw.start()
        pr.start()
        pw.join()
        pr.join()
```

**write.py**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def write(record_queue, table_queue):
    thread_num = 3
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_num)
    futures = [pool.submit(run, record_queue, table_queue) for _ in range (thread_num)]
    results = [r.result() for r in as_completed(futures)]


def run(record_queue, table_queue):
    while True:
        if  table_queue.empty():
            break
    table = table_queue.get()
    # adding this code below reduce deadlock opportunity.
    #import time
    #import random
    #time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    process_with_table(record_queue, table_queue, table)

def process_with_table(record_queue, table_queue, table):
    #for short
    for item in [x for x in range(1000)]:
        record_queue.put(item)
```

**read.py**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import threading
import Queue

def read(record_queue, table_queue):
    count = 0
    while True:

        item = record_queue.get()
        count += 1
        print ("item: ", item)
        if count == 4:
            break
```

I googled it and there are same questions on SO, but i cant see the similarity compared with my code, so can anyone help my codes, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to find a solution, change run method in write module to :

```
def run(record_queue, table_queue):
    while True:
        try:  
             if table_queue.empty():
                 break
             table = table_queue.get(timeout=3)

             process_with_table(record_queue, table_queue, table)
        except multiprocessing.queues.Empty:
             import time
             time.sleep(0.1)
```

and never see deadlock or blocking on get method.